# JqGrid use of index property of colModel instead of name Property during both Sorting and Searching

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

**Question**:

using jqgrid to show data of a table. table has foreign key and we want to show text of its foreign key instead of Id. I also want that user can sort and filter over the foreign keys.

**Example**:

- Person Table: Id,Name,EducationId(foreign key for Education Table)
- Education able: Id,Name

We want to show each person with the name of his/her education name in a jqgrid.

1. If user click over education column, it sort according to `Education Name`(Not `Education Id`)
2. If User want to filter over education, we show a dropdown(selector) that contain education Names,after user select one, the filter contain `EducationId` as `sField` and `Id` of selected value as `sValue`

**My Solution**:

```
var items1 = {@Html.GetEduType()};

$(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/GridData/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Name','Education'],
            colModel: [
          { name: 'Name', index: 'Name' },
          { name: 'EducationId', index: 'Education.Name', search: true, 
             stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: items1, sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] },
             formatter: 'select' , editoptions: { value: items1 }}],            
            viewrecords: true});
$("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true });
```

1. With this code, `Home/GetData` just send `Person.Id`, `Person.Name`, `Person.EducationId` as json data and it is really good to not send more data than client needs. Also it send relation between `Education Id` and `Name` once and these data used for showing name instead of id in grid, and also to create dropdown value and text.
2. I ignore to write other properties like pager, pagesize, etc
3. `@Html.GetEduType()` is razor server side function. It just returns pairs like 
   `[Education Id]:[Education Name]`. For example: (`1:'Diploma',2:'M.S.',...`) (I just use it to get education data once and did not use `UrlData`)
   (Yes, I use it in ASP.Net MVC 3, but its not an important point)

**My Problem**:
It work great for showing data and sorting Education according to its name. But when I want to filter Education it send index value(`Education.Name`)  instead of name value (`EducationId`) in Http Post `sField` to server. This problem will be solved just by sending name value instead of index value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem in this way:

1. First of all, I handle `beforeSearch` event:

   ```
   .filterToolbar({ stringResult: true, beforeSearch: searchPreparation })
   ```
2. Here is `searchPreparation` function:

   ```
   function searchPreparation(grid) {
     if (grid == undefined)
         grid = $(this);
     else
         grid = $(grid);
     var postData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
     var searchData = jQuery.parseJSON(postData.filters);
     var gridCol = grid.getGridParam("colModel");
     for (var i = 0; i < searchData.rules.length; i++) {
         for (var j = 0; j < gridCol.length; j++) {
             if (gridCol[j].index != gridCol[j].name && searchData.rules[i].field == gridCol[j].name) {
                 searchData.rules[i].field = gridCol[j].index;
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
     grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { filters: JSON.stringify(searchData)} });
     return false;
   }
   ```

In `searchPreparation` first I get post data and parse it. After that I search for columns that their indexes are not equal to their name and find that whether is there any filter with these columns. If there is any column, I replace field with index.
Finally I set the post data. Notify that data convert to JSON with `JSON.stringify` that you can find it [here](http://www.json.org/js.html).

I use this function for filter data with dropdown either (use value of drop down's items not text)

Comment: `searchData.rules[i].field = gridCol[j].index`
single = instead of ==. was looking for a mistake for 15 minutes and couldn't understand why it doesn't work